# How to VLOOKUP to see whether ONLY the months and year add up?

Tags: xml, excel

I'm basically trying to find a way to create a VLOOKUP (or another function) on Excel to be able to add the values in an adjacent column to some dates, only when they match the dates of another column, this example will make it more clear.

```
      A1        B1       C1         D1
-------------------------------------------                            
1   01/04/16          04/04/16      1.5
2   01/05/16          12/05/16        2
3   01/06/16          23/05/16      0.5
4   01/07/16          04/06/16      2.5
5   01/08/16          13/06/16        2
6   01/09/16          24/06/16        1
7   01/10/16          05/07/16      3.5
8   01/11/16          12/07/16        4
```

Essentially, what I want in this example above is to be able to have a way where any dates in C1 with the same month and date as A1 to add their adjacent D1 value in B1.

e.g. B2 should equal 2.5 due to C2 & C3 falling under the same month and year as A2 --> then their values in D1 are summed together for a total B2 value.

Thanks in advance!

I will further clarify if it isn't clear :)

Comment: Welcome to [so], maybe you can post your expected result too?

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the below formula in B1 then copy and paste the same to other rows of column B.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT($C$1:$C$8,"YYYYMM")=TEXT(A1,"YYYYMM"))*$D$1:$D$8)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Karpak! (sorry I can't upvote --> New Account). If you don't mind, can you explain how the last *$D$1$:$D$8 part works, I don't get why you multiply (maybe you don't - but that's how I perceived it). But the main thing is it does work! :)

Comment: Nevermind, I think I worked it out, so basically (please correct me if I'm wrong) when the array is true, it gets assigned '1' which is then multiplied by the sum of $D$1:$D$8, when there aren't any values found, the array is assigned 0 and multiplied by the sum of 0. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You are right. if you see this is correct answer. please accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this array formula, put it into `B1` and press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` and fill down:

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH($C$1:$C$8)=MONTH(A1),$D$1:$D$8))
```